# Can I determine the way the titlebar looks of a UWP app?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to give the titlebar the look and feel of the style of the app. I'm using XAML with C# to write this UWP app.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following (usually at app launch):

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

view.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = ;
view.TitleBar.ForegroundColor = ;

view.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = ;
view.TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = ;

view.TitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
view.TitleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = Colors.White;

view.TitleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = ;
view.TitleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = ;

view.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = ;
view.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = ;

view.TitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = ;
view.TitleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = ;
```

**Extra Bonus**
If you want to extend your app's UI into the `TitleBar`, that is also possible. [This blog post](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952) has an excellent example, here's a summary:

```
CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lance McCarthy's answer only works on on Desktop.
His code will run on Mobile wuithout an Exception, but won't actually change the StatusBar, so you won't see any effect there.
For Mobile you need the "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP" from nuget then you can change the StatusBar on phones, too:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
   var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
   if (statusBar != null)
   {
      statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 81, 81, 81); // light gray color
   }
}
```